# List of dicts from unique values across multiple fields in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a queryset 'elements' containing instances of the model Element. Elements have a foreign key 'series', and each series has fields:

```
subtopic_1_name
subtopic_1_slug
subtopic_2_name
subtopic_2_slug
subtopic_3_name
subtopic_3_slug
```

I need to generate a "flattened" list of dicts of the form

```
[{'name': 'somename', 'slug': 'someslug'}, {'name': 'anothername' 'slug': 'anotherslug'}, ... ]
```

where 'name' and 'slug' correspond to unique values from the three name and slug fields, excluding the empty string. I currently am using an inefficient for loop with 'not in' to check for uniqueness. It works but is too slow because 'elements' can have up to 1.9M members.

What is an efficient way to do this?

Update:

Here's the best I have so far, but there must be a faster way:

```
subtopic_list = []
ones = elements.values_list('series__subtopic1_name', 'series__subtopic1_slug').distinct()
twos = elements.values_list('series__subtopic2_name', 'series__subtopic2_slug').distinct()
threes = elements.values_list('series__subtopic3_name', 'series__subtopic3_slug').distinct()
for num in [ones, twos, threes]:
    for name, slug in num:
        if name != '':
            subtopic_list.append({'name': name, 'slug': slug)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about filtering the empty names in the db query using 'exclude'?

```
ones = elements.exclude('series__subtopic1_name'='').\
   values_list('series__subtopic1_name','series__subtopic1_slug').distinct()

twos = elements.exclude('series__subtopic2_name'='').\
   values_list('series__subtopic2_name', 'series__subtopic2_slug').distinct()

threes = elements.exclude('series__subtopic3_name'='').\
   values_list('series__subtopic3_name', 'series__subtopic3_slug').distinct()

# concatenate element of twos and threes into list 'ones'
ones.extend(twos)
ones.extend(threes)

# we already filtered empty names in the db query,
# so we can just return the subtopic_list
subtopic_list = [{'name': name, 'slug': slug} for name, slug in ones]
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for a way to avoid the need for the three distinct() calls, but this is cleaner code.

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of the distinct() calls? It's possible, but in your question you mentioned you wanted to eliminate the expensive for loop.